# looping over jekyll collections

Tags: loops, jekyll, liquid

I have the following code

```
<div>
 {% for note in site.regnotes %}
   {% if note.regulationno == page.regulationno %}
     <p>
      {{ note.regulationno }} - {{ note.url }}
     </p>
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

This code loops over the regnotes collection in a jekyll site, checks if the current note regulationno is the same as the page regulationno and if so displays the regulationno and url - that is the url of the current page. How do I change this code to include the url of the previous page, the current page and the next page. I'm looking for three urls - previous, current and next? - The "page.previous.url" variable within jekyll does not appear to work in collections.

This is what it might look like in other code

```
for i=1 to number of items in the regnotes collection
  if current note == page note
    print page[i].url        //current page url
    print page[i-1].url      //previous page url
    print page[i+1].url      //next page url
  end if
end for
```

I suppose what I'm trying todo is reference the items in the collection by their array index. just can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're looking for. The URL of the page you're in would be at page.url. As for next and previous pages, Jekyll's built in pagination only works on posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are a programmer, you just need to know that you need to use forloop.index0 to know where you are in the for loop (https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/for-loops#index0).

The code will be something like:

```
<div>
 {% for note in site.regnotes %}
   {% assign current_index = forloop.index0 }}
   {% assign next_index = current_index | plus: 1 %}
   {% assign prev_index = current_index | minus: 1 %}
   {% if note.regulationno == page.regulationno %}
     <p>
      {{ note.regulationno }} - {{ note.url }}
     </p>
     {% if site.regnotes[prev_index] %}<a href="{{ site.regnotes[prev_index].url }}">prev</a>{% endif %}
     {% if site.regnotes[next_index] %}<a href="{{ site.regnotes[next_index].url }}">next</a>{% endif %}
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```